# Laravel after form post sweet alert

Tags: laravel, sweetalert2

I am posting my inputs controller in laravel. Then recording database, after redirecting page want to show sweet alert just like this "Item has been added successfully". Is that possible ?

Answer (score 4):

You can keep flash data in controller ,like this

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Item has been added successfully!');
```

and on view you can do this

```
@if (session('status'))
    <script>
      Swal.fire("{{ session('status') }}");
    </script>
@endif
```

for more info please visit [Flash Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#flash-data)

Comment: Thank you @seymur-omarov