# Laravel alert message

Tags: html, laravel

I'm currently developing a website, using a laravel framework. And now i'm stuck on how to make an alert message in the create page website[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThgRY.png). Here's the layout of the website form.

How to create an alert message(Not pop up, or window. Literally alert message)??

here 's the code
`<div class="form-group"> <label>NIK</label> <input type="text" id="kredit_nik" name="kredit_nik" class="form-control" placeholder="Contoh : 3152021502002002"> </div><br>`
I'm using HTML5 for this one

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself. 
Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), 
read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: clientside or serverside?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel after form post sweet alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52666003/laravel-after-form-post-sweet-alert)

Answer (score 1):

If you use laravel blade, you can validate the request in the controller. Then you can use

```
@error('kredit_nik')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

The `class alert alert-danger` is a bootstrap class. If you don't use bootstrap you can make your own error class

source: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages